# How do you make DISPLAY variable undefined?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I am using Ubuntu, but I think this applies to all Linux.

What's the command to set DISPLAY to be undefined in the shell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the `unset` command: `unset DISPLAY`

Comment: You can also disable it temporarily for a single command: `DISPLAY= emacs` (though `emacs -nw` is easier — and indeed most applications with both X and terminal interfaces already have an option to disable their X versions).